# How can I put my button in the center in Ruby on rails?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a button that has a link on the left side of screen.

```
<div class="col-md-4" text-center>
<%=  button_to("Bay Area Time", { action: "index" , :timezone=>'west'}, class: "btn btn-primary")  %>
</div>
```

I want to put this button in the center of a certain box. Where should I make modifications to achieve this? How can I center my button, especially when I'm trying to incorporate action, and the variable inside the hyper link? :)

Answer (score 0):

`<div class="col-md-4 text-center"'>`

You have forgot to include text-center in double quotes of classfor that tag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the text-center inside the class declaration. In your code it is outside of the quotes and will have no effect. This should do what you want if the area in which you are trying to center the button is indeed the col-md-4 gridspace. I am assuming you are including the Bootstrap css code correctly as that is a bootstrap grid class.

```
<div class="col-md-4 text-center" > 
<%=  button_to("Bay Area Time", { action: "index" , :timezone=>'west'}, class: "btn btn-primary")  %>
</div>
```